# update dataframe from dataframe with priority

Tags: python, pandas

```
for i in cricos: #list of dicts
    vet = i['VET Code']
    name = i['Course Name'] 
    for i2 in website: #list of dicts
        if i2['VET Code'] == vet and i2['Course Name'] ==name:
            i.update(i2) #update cricos dictionary giving priority to it's key-value
```

the above works but I want to convert code to `pandas`

How can I do the same when I use `pandas`

```
cricos = pd.read_csv('cricos.csv') #15 columns
website = pd.read_csv('web.csv') # 20 columns (7 columns will be the same as from cricos but different values)
```

Comment: could you provide a sample data and expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use either [`pandas.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) or [`pandas.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

By doing a `'inner'` merge you can obtain updated rows that are in `website` :

```py
primary_key = ['VET Code', 'Course Name']
columns_not_in_common = [col for col in website.columns if col not in cricos.columns]

cricos_updated = (
    cricos
    .loc[:, primary_key + columns_not_in_common]
    .merge(website, on=primary_key, how='inner')
    )
```

Then you can concat the result with not updated rows

You could also use a `groupby`-based method :

```py
primary_key = ['VET Code', 'Course Name']

website_info = website.groupby(primary_key )
for key, values in cricos.groupby(primary_key):
    try:
        infos = website_info.get_group(key)
    except:
        continue

    cricos.loc[values.index, infos.columns] = list(infos.iloc[0])
```